# Vue static assets are not accessible to a library

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, face-api

I am using a single file Vue component and import a face-api library. I want to use a function from that library, `loadSsdMobilenetv1Model(url)`, which takes URL of folder, where the necessary files are located and loads them. The function however cannot fetch the files if I use `@/assets/weights` as url (@ in Vue represents the src folder). I would like to be able to host the assets for. I'm able to read files from the `assets` folder folder with `require('@/assets/file.json)`, but the library seems to need a static url.

What is the best solution in my situation? Maybe I'm missing some understanding.
Can I make it so that the `assets` folder is served and accessible?

Here's my component and the comments show some things I've tried:

```
<template>
  <div>...stuff...</div>
</template>

<script>

import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';

async function load() {
  
  // example below: If I serve the files on a separate port with CORS allowed, the function loads files fine. 
  // const MODEL_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/weights/'; 

  // example below: this does not work, but I would like this to work!
     const MODEL_URL = '@/assets/weights';

  // example below: also doesn't work, conscious of  relative paths
  // const MODEL_URL = '../assets/weights'; 

  // example below: a file loads, but I can't just this unfortunately
  // return require('@/assets/file.json')

  return await faceapi.loadSsdMobilenetv1Model(MODEL_URL);
}


export default {


  mounted() {
    var promise = load();

    promise.then((model) => {
      this.model = model
    }, (reject) => {
      console.log(reject)
      // alert(reject);
    })

  },
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
       model: null
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I set up the project with

```
vue create
```

and run the dev environment with

```
nmp run serve
```

Comment: Did you try to convert data to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs , in case it supports this? Notice that the docs say how to deal with data directly, https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html#usage-loading-models

Comment: just reading the github there is other methoods to load data like this one : `await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk('./models')`
does it work ?